# Dynamic Text in SVG def

Tags: html, svg, text, dynamic

I'm trying to use an svg def tag to show some dimensions in a creative manner.

For an example, I have below example svg def.

```
    <svg>
    <defs>
        <g id="aaa" stroke-opacity="null" stroke-width="0"  stroke-linecap="null"  stroke-linejoin="null" fill="#6bfc46" >
             <circle cx="300" cy="400" r="30" />
             <rect x="300" y="400" width="30" height="30" />
             <circle cx="300" cy="400" r="25" fill="#ffffff" />
             <text x="300" y="400" text-anchor="middle" stroke="#6bfc46" stroke-width="2px" dy=".3em">5</text>  
        </g>
    </defs>
    <svg/>
```

What I need to achieve is I should be able to use this defined text in different locations as below.

```
<use xlink:href="#aaa" x="480" y="550" changing_text="3">
<use xlink:href="#aaa" x="580" y="650" changing_text="9">
```

My Question is

1) Is this possible with SVG ?

2) How can we achieve this ?

Comment: why not just create text elements with text in insted of use elements. You can style the text elements with a class so they are all stroke red and text-anchor middle etc.

Comment: I have to use this text inside a marker. For an example text inside a google pin. Text inside a user icon and etc. So I need the svg text to deal with the resizing of the map.

Comment: There is no marker element in your question. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @RobertLongson Edited the question.

Comment: There's no obvious way to do that other than create two different defs elements.